# Play Games Services Achievements Disappearing

Tags: flutter, google-play, google-play-games

Play Game achievements unlocked in app don't persist after clearing the Play Games Services cache and restarting the app. When I test and successfully unlock achievements, but these are not reflected when clearing the cache and relaunching (or relaunching after sometimes).

I've used `games_services` package & the code for unlocking achievement is

```
GamesServices.unlock(
        achievement: Achievement(
          androidID: '####',
          percentComplete: 100.0,
        ),
      );
```

I've also submitted score to the Leaderboard

```
GamesServices.submitScore(
      score: Score(
        androidLeaderboardID: '###',
        value: score,
      ),
    );
```

Details:

- Play Games Services integration confirmed successful.
- User count displays correctly in the Play Console.
- Achievements are properly configured and enabled in the Google Play Console.
- Users sign in successfully before unlocking achievements.
- Detailed logging implemented, showing successful unlocking events and API calls.
- No relevant error reports in the Google Play Console.
- Achievement unlocking logic thoroughly reviewed and verified.
- Tested on multiple devices, Android versions, and Play Games accounts.
- Latest Play Games Services SDK version used.
- Official documentation and troubleshooting guides reviewed.
- Community forums consulted but no similar issues found.

Additional Information:

- App Name: [Ludo Master](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ludomaster.ludo.master) (In case if you want to Test)
- `implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-games-v2:+"`
- Play Games Services SDK Version: `4.0.0`